# Please explain this OCaml type definition

Tags: ocaml

Record definition:

```
type t = {name: string}
```

Variant definition :

```
type thing = Thing1 | Thing2;
```

**Can anyone example what the following snippet defines?**

```
type ('a, 'b) t =
   Blah : ((('a, 'b) Tea_result.t -> unit) -> unit) -> ('a, 'b) t
```

More Generally, this structure:

```
type t = Blah : xxx
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Generalized Algebraic Data Type - have a look at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85